# Custom attributes?

Tags: attributes

Is it possible to assign custom attributes to symbols and check them later?

```
SetAttributes[a, b]
```

says

```
Attributes::attnf: b is not a known attribute.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, I do not believe it is.  As the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/message/Attributes/attnf.html) for your error message says:

> The attributes available in each version of Mathematica are fixed and cannot be changed.

The system attributes are low level properties that fundamentally change the evaluation of symbols.  I think it makes sense that these are not mixed with high-level user constructs, even though at times that would be quite convenient.

For an alternative remember that you can attach `Options` to a symbol, e.g.:

```
Options[a] = {"Attributes" -> {"b"}};

OptionValue[a, "Attributes"]
```

> ```
> {"b"}
> ```

You could also use a single `DownValues` rule such as:

```
a["Attributes"] = {"b"};

a["Attributes"]
```

> ```
> {"b"}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. But how to change individual option of a symbol?

Comment: Ah, I found `SetOptions` function.

Comment: @Suzan What do you mean?  It is simple to *replace* the list of options with either method shown, e.g. `SetOptions[a, "Attributes" -> {"c", "d"}];` or `a["Attributes"] = {"c", "d"};`  Are you asking for a way to individually append or remove these values as `SetAttributes` and `ClearAttributes` do?  I could add that to my answer if you have trouble crafting it yourself.

Comment: @Suzan Thanks for the Accept, but please consider waiting a while first as someone else may have an answer you like better if you do not discourage them from reading the question.